# Custom json converter json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize a complex JSON object and the "JsonSerializer().Deserialize" dosent work well on this specific object,  [Link to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475751/deserialize-json-object-to-array/29477002?noredirect=1#comment47118835_29477002). Now I'm trying to do custom Deserialization and i'm stuck since i'm not familiar with C# or JSON format. 
please help me.
Example of the JSON data:

```
    {"stationary_osbtacles": [
    {
      "latitude": 33.83320,
      "longitude": 33.83320,
      "cylinder_radius": 33.83320,
      "cylinder_height": 33.83320
    }
  ],
  "moving_obstacles": [
    {
      "latitude": 33.83320,
      "longitude": 33.83320,
      "altitude_msl": 33.83320,
      "sphere_radius": 33.83320
    }
  ]}
```

**EDIT:** Here's an example of the JSON data I get from the server
[image]

and a real text file for example:

{"stationary_obstacles": [{"latitude": 20.0, "cylinder_height": 4323.0, "cylinder_radius": 345.0, "longitude": 20.0}], "moving_obstacles": [{"latitude": 20.0, "sphere_radius": 50.0, "altitude_msl": 100.0, "longitude": 20.0}, {"latitude": 35.0, "sphere_radius": 453.0, "altitude_msl": 45345.0, "longitude": 35.0}, {"latitude": 0.0, "sphere_radius": 3242.0, "altitude_msl": 0.14, "longitude": 0.0}]}

Comment: Why does the built-in deserialization not work for you? What have you tried to do yourself? This isn't the place to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON objects to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447558/deserializing-json-objects-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475751/deserialize-json-object-to-array/). Now you just changed some values in your JSON from int to float. I will paste code from my existing answer with small changes.

**EDIT**: You do not need to create you models manually. There are many options to generate them based on your JSON. For example:

- **Visual Studio**. If you copy your JSON to clipboard and in `Visual Studio click EDIT -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes` it will generate class structure for you.
- [**json2csharp.com**](http://json2csharp.com/). Web based tool for generating classes from
  JSON.

These models are generated using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/):

```
public class StationaryObstacle
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double cylinder_height { get; set; }
    public double cylinder_radius { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}

public class MovingObstacle
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double sphere_radius { get; set; }
    public double altitude_msl { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<StationaryObstacle> stationary_obstacles { get; set; }
    public List<MovingObstacle> moving_obstacles { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization using JSON.NET:

```
var json = "{\"stationary_obstacles\":[{\"latitude\":20.0,\"cylinder_height\":4323.0,\"cylinder_radius\":345.0,\"longitude\":20.0}],\"moving_obstacles\":[{\"latitude\":20.0,\"sphere_radius\":50.0,\"altitude_msl\":100.0,\"longitude\":20.0},{\"latitude\":35.0,\"sphere_radius\":453.0,\"altitude_msl\":45345.0,\"longitude\":35.0},{\"latitude\":0.0,\"sphere_radius\":3242.0,\"altitude_msl\":0.14,\"longitude\":0.0}]}";

// Option 1
var d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

// Option 2
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
{
    var d2 = (RootObject)new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(stringReader, typeof(RootObject));
}
```

Comment: I updated `json` property. If you replace both models and code for deserialization, you will see that it works.

Comment: Ok, This way it works. But I'm trying to get the JSON from a server as you saw in my previous question. Why it does not work there?

Comment: I added an example of how the JSON data really looks like when I get it from the server

Comment: Can you replace example JSON with real one (as text). And also provide exception details.

Comment: I added a text example

Comment: Check my edit. Now `json` property contains real JSON provided by you. And everything works ;)

Comment: I have no idea what was the problem but now it works! You are amazing Thank you very much!